# Error "Cannot unset string offsets" exporting using custom field mapping

Tags: smartgroups, export

I'm running civiCRM  5.17.5 under Joomla 3.9.12

When I select a specific smart group with a saved field mapping for export, and select "Exclude contacts with "do not mail" privacy, no street address, or who are deceased.",

I get the error (note the error doesn't appear if I don't select Exclude contacts...):

`Error#8247
message => string(27) "Cannot unset string offsets"string => string(0) ""
code => 0
file => string(102) "/home/fcwm/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Export/BAO/ExportProcessor.php"
line => 176
trace => array (20)
previous => NULL`

`Cannot unset string offsets
.../administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Export/BAO/ExportProcessor.php:176
171   public function setAdditionalFieldsForPostalExport() {
172     if ($this->getRequestedFields() && $this->isPostalableOnly()) {
173       $fields = ['is_deceased', 'do_not_mail', 'street_address', 'supplemental_address_1'];
174       foreach ($fields as $index => $field) {
175         if (!empty($this->getReturnProperties()[$field])) {
176           unset($field[$index]);
177         }
178       }
179       $this->additionalFieldsForPostalExport = array_fill_keys($fields, 1);
180     }
181   }`

This error wasn't occurring prior to upgrading to 5.17.5

It doesn't happen with all my Saved field mappings, just one of them (but one I've been using for a few years without issue).

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in today's release (5.18.1)

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a typo in the code and line 176 should be `unset($fields[$index])` (plural fields).

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1292

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15392

Note that to trigger it you have to check that checkbox and also have one of the affected fields in your export mapping, like "Street Address".